# power bi, leading zero issue in funtion

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have this function which retrieves data if license number is valid. Eg.10002212. The function is not accepting a valid license number with leading ZERO, 08001366 and is erroring out. How can I make the function accept valid licenses with leading ZERO?.

Thank you.

```
(LicenceNumber) =>
let
Source = 
Web.Page(Web.Contents("http://mbsweblist.fsco.gov.on.ca/ShowLicence.aspx?M" 
& Number.ToText(LicenceNumber) & "~")),
WebData = Source{1}[Data],
#"Extracted Text Before Delimiter" = Table.TransformColumns(WebData, 
{{"Column1", each Text.BeforeDelimiter(_, ":"), type text}}),
#"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(#"Extracted Text Before Delimiter",1),
#"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Removed Top Rows"),
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Transposed Table", 
[PromoteAllScalars=true])
in
#"Promoted Headers"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know your licence number should always be 8 characters long, you can use `Text.PadStart` to add leading zeroes:

```
(LicenceNumber) =>
let
    LicenceText = Text.PadStart(Number.ToText(LicenceNumber,8,"0")
    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("http://mbsweblist.fsco.gov.on.ca/ShowLicence.aspx?M"& LicenceText & "~")),
    WebData = Source{1}[Data],
    #"Extracted Text Before Delimiter" = Table.TransformColumns(WebData, {{"Column1", each Text.BeforeDelimiter(_, ":"), type text}}),
    #"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(#"Extracted Text Before Delimiter",1),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Removed Top Rows"),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Transposed Table", [PromoteAllScalars=true])
in
    #"Promoted Headers"
```

Comment: That does it !! Thank you Olly